# Why release app not working as the debug app?

Tags: flutter

I made a flutter app for online radio.
It works fine on debug app. but on the release app, it gives a socket exception.

This is the audio plugin that i used.
https://pub.dev/packages/audio_stream_player

How can i fix it?

Comment: You have to put here your code and error description

Comment: Check release AndroidManifest for android.permission.INTERNET permission

Comment: @rstrelba Yes. That was the problem and thank you.

Comment: Check my answer as right plz.

Comment: @rstrelba it's a comment. Add an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check release AndroidManifest.xml for android.permission.INTERNET permission
[image]